# Spring Data R2DBC - Backpressure not taken into account?

Tags: spring-data, project-reactor, r2dbc, spring-data-r2dbc

This thread is a continuation of the Github issue at: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-r2dbc/issues/194

Context:

Hi,

I just tried a very simple Exemple, based on two reactive repositories:

Given  `br`, a r2dbc crud repo, and `cr`, another r2dbc crud repo:

```java
br.findAll()
   .flatMap(br -> {
      return cr.findById(br.getPropertyOne())
               .doOnNext(c -> br.setProperty2(c))
               .thenReturn(br);
    })
   .collectList().block();
```

This code samples never completes (only the 250 first, or so, entries reach the `.collectList` operator). After some digging, adding some `onBackpressureXXX` operator after the `findAll` seems to "fix" the issue by... well, dropping elements or buffering them.

At this point, my understanding is that the r2dbc reactive repositories doesn't uses the consumer feedback mechanism which removes a significant part of r2dbc's benefits.

Am I wrong ? Is there any better way to achieve the same objective ?

Thanks !

---

Suggestion from @mp911de:

Avoid stream creation while another stream is active (Famous quote: Do not cross the streams) as general rule.

If you want to fetch related data, then ideally collect all results as List and then run subqueries. This way, the initial response stream is consumed and the connection is free to fetch additional results.

Something like the following snippet should do the job:

```
br.findAll().collectList()
        .flatMap(it -> {

            List<Mono<Reference>> refs = new ArrayList<>();
            for (Person p : it) {
                 refs.add(cr.findById(br.getPropertyOne()).doOnNext(…));
            }

            return Flux.concat(refs).thenReturn(it);
        });
```

---

But this removes the benefit of streaming the data without keeping it all in memory (my final step not being to list but to stream-write to output to some file).

Any help on this one ?

Comment: Were you able to solve this? If so would you please share? I'm running into a similar situation.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue and the github thread guided me towards the right way. There is no silver bullet for this problem, except looking for these 2 things:

1. Any streams that operate inside a transaction
2. Multiple streams that operate in the same scope

Especially the last point is not easy to find. For OP it was a `findAll()` that was was supplying data continuously (stream 1) and a `flatMap` that **concurrently** modifies data for each emitted result the moment it is read (stream 2).

In my case it was different. The route cause was the execution of a `flatMap` inside a `flatMap`. What makes it possibly hard to find is when you pass a `Publisher` as argument. Suppose you have this code:

```java
@Transactional
public Mono<Render> saveInPostgres(final Long sequenceNumber,
                                   final Mono<SomeComputeResult> previousOperations) {  
        previousOperations.flatMap(computeResult -> {
            computeResult.updateSequenceNumber(sequenceNumber);
            Render render = computeResult.finalize();
            final Mono<Render> saved = renderRepository.save(entity);
            ...
        }
```

I'm passing a `Mono`, which is then executed via the `flatMap`. After updating the sequence number the method saves the object in the repository. Naturally all the operations that led to the `Mono` are now executed the moment you map. What you cannot see here is:

1. `saveInPostgres` was itself called inside a `flatMap`
2. `previousOperations.flatMap()` ran in an error i.e. exception

This behaviour was especially painful for us, because the exceptions happend at a time, when there was a lock on the database and the locks kept on accumulating and draining our connection pool until the service was unresponsive.

**Hints for fixing the Problem**

So my 2 cents, if you have `Publisher`s as arguments, remove them. Always chain your mapping executions instead of passing them and possibly creating streams whithin streams. This is essentially the same with OPs problem. By calling `collectList()` he was able to chain the operations because `findAll()` was done before any other modifications were done on the elements via the second `flatMap`.